# Make target is not hitting

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run build with some new changes in makefile where new folder needs to be created and place some files in that folder.

Here is my target placed in my make file:

```
    tools_mvv32: $(RELEASE_FILES) ## Which has files pointing to TGTTEST32

    define file_copy
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -f $< $@
    endef

    TGTTEST32 := /home_test/workspace/copy/limited_projects/src/main/scp/build/Linux/project/primary/ktl
    $(TGTTEST32)/tools/bin/%: $(TGTTEST32)/bin/%
           $(file_copy)
```

When i try to run build by placing the target i.e. with specific file name with hardcoded as follows, It works fine

```
/home_test/workspace/copy/limited_projects/src/main/scp/build/Linux/project/primary/ktl/tools/bin/mpf: /home_test/workspace/copy/limited_projects/src/main/scp/build/Linux/project/primary/ktl/bin/mpf
   $(file_copy)
```

May i know if any syntax is incorrect in my generic target ?

I am hitting below issue with my generic target:

```
gmake: *** No rule to make target /home_test/workspace/copy/limited_projects/src/main/scp/build/Linux/project/primary/ktl/tools/mpf
```

Comment: `ktl/tools/bin/mpf`, or `ktl/tools/mpf`, or `ktl/mpf`? It looks like you've misspelt your path.

Comment: Your paths are too long and hence are error-prone.

Comment: @Marr, I have updated my question.. Please check?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, I dont think its because of too long paths...As i have other targers same way which is working fine.

Comment: Your Makefile has no default goal so its behaviour depends on the goal you pass on the command line. What command do you type **exactly**?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, i just copied makfile snippet. Not whole makefile.

Comment: I am calling make with target 'tools_mvv32' ..Please check above. I just updated my query.

Comment: Sorry but you really do not help us helping you. What is `RELEASE_FILES`? The error message you get (`gmake: *** No rule to make target /home_test/.../ktl/tools/mpf`) does not make sense with what you show. `gmake: *** No rule to make target /home_test/.../ktl/bin/mpf` or `gmake: *** No rule to make target /home_test/.../ktl/tools/bin/mpf` would make sense but not what you get. Unless you show us a real [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I am afraid we will be unable to help.